# AWS lambda No module named markupsafe error with jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jinja2, python-3.6

I created a lambda function to send emails in a specific template and for the template i am using jinja2 packaged along with lambda. My lambda import statements are like this below:

```
import datetime
import boto3
import threading
import time

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from libs.jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
```

[image]

and my libs folder consists of jinja2 and when it failed with `No module named Markupsafe` i pip installed markupsafe into the libs folder as target and zipped the app(source code) and libs folder together. But it still doesn't work and fails with this below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app.main': No module named 'markupsafe'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the similar problem, our aws lambda uses runtime **python3.7**

So **jinja2** depends on **markupsafe** [1]

```
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
Downloading Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.0.2
Downloading Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==0.14.1
Downloading Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322 kB)
....
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
```

The above dependecy tree works .

[1] https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/intro/#prerequisites

Comment: Thank you for the response! After adding the packages into the zip, i added PYTHONPATH environment variable to let lamdba use the libs.
`PYTHONPATH /var/runtime:/var/task/libs`